# How to handle asynctask during phone call and apps in background android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

i have made an app, which sending/receiving lat long to/from server continuously.also retrieving and showing information from server.i have used asynctask for network call. but one problem when phonecall came and apps in background my apps lost its connection;like not show any server information nor send lat long to server in right destination. how to solve this? **like if i would use volley then singleton class may help to solve this problem** is there any solution for asynctask?

this is my asynctask:

```
     import android.app.ProgressDialog;
        import android.content.Context;

        import android.os.AsyncTask;

        import android.util.Log;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.BufferedWriter;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.io.OutputStream;
        import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

        import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
        import java.net.MalformedURLException;
        import java.net.URL;


public class
GetPostAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    public AsyncResult asyncResult;
//    HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection;


//    private static String responseStr = "";
//    private static String responseStrLogin = "";



    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    private final String baseUrl = UserInfo.getBaseUrl();

    Context context;


        GetPostAsyncTask(Context context,AsyncResult asyncResult) {

            this.context=context;
            this.asyncResult= asyncResult;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //Toast.makeText(context,"Loading..",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog=new ProgressDialog(context);
            progressDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            try {
                // setting the URL
                URL url = new URL(baseUrl+args[1]);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "RealTimeApps/1.0");
                // setting the method type
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(args[0]);
    //                httpURLConnection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));

                Log.v("Url",args[2]);
                // setting the identification key name with query params
                bufferedWriter.write(args[2]);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();

                Log.v("GetPostA", url.toString());

                httpURLConnection.connect();
                int getPostStatus = httpURLConnection.getResponseCode();

                Log.v("GetPostSts", String.valueOf(getPostStatus));



                String line = "";
                String res = "";
    //                if(getPostStatus == 200){

                // prepare the output buffer
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"));

                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

                    res += line;

                }

                inputStream.close();

    //                }

                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return res.toString();

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("GetPostCatchMal",e.toString());

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.v("GetPostCatchIOE", e.toString());
            }

            return null;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            if(result!=null) {
                asyncResult.asyncResult(result);
            }
        }

    }
```

i am very new in android and unable to find the solution of this problem.any help please. TIA

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to listen to incoming calls using an IncomingCallReceiver (user-defined : code given below) and suspend/stop your Asynctask when you receive a call, and resume/restart it when the call ends.

**For stop-restart case**:
In your Asynctask you can make it loop on a *sharedpreference* flag variable for continuous behavior and set the flag to false when call comes. When call ends, you can initiate the Asynctask again.

Code for IncomingCallReceiver:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {                            
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                              // 2
    this.context = context;
    try{

     String state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);  

     if (TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state))
     {
          //Call incoming
     }
     else if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK.equals(state))
     {
         //Call picked up
     }
     else if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE.equals(state))
     {
         //Call ends 
     }
     }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**Incoming call receiver tutorial:** http://www.theappguruz.com/blog/detecting-incoming-phone-calls-in-android

**Shared preferences tutorial :** https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_shared_preferences.htm

**Asynctask tutorial:** https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

**Singleton class tutorial:** https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/singleton

Comment: how to handle this while i am using asynctask class as common and calling from multiple activity.

Comment: It should not make any difference if you follow my methodology....since whichever asynctask is running..the looping depends only on the sharedpreference flag variable

Comment: seems your solution is like what what i am searching for. i very new in android, can you please give an working example of your ans please.how to use it in my code.

Comment: I can point you in the right direction with respect to the elements needed...but you will need to put the pieces together...since i do not know the complete picture

Comment: okay thank you very much. up-voted. any other way to handle this situation i mentioned above ?

Comment: and thank you if you can provide any example link it will be the best.

Comment: You can also try make your asynctask a singleton class so that at any time...only one instance of asynctask can exist...and u can track that in your multiple activities

Comment: i up-voted your ans before you told. okay thank you and now its my time to give a try on it. can i directly connect with you please? by email, facebook or any social media?

Answer (score 1):

You can run that code in a [Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html). The service can run in the background (even when app is paused/stopped) - which means that even when a phone call comes in (which puts your activity in paused state) your code should run without interruptions.

Make sure you read more about the lifecycle of the Service to implement what you're trying to do properly.

EDIT:

To run the AsyncTask within the Service, create an instance of that task when creating the Service (see Service [lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)) and run the task there.

When you try to start a Service that is already running, it won't create another instance but rather will return an instance of the running Service, however it will call onStartCommand again.

You can [bind](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) the service to your activity(s) to communicate with it.

Comment: how to handle this while i am using asynctask class as common and calling from multiple activity.

Comment: thanks, i read the lifecycle but which one is called during/after phonecall, though i know service runs in background is there any state like onstartcommand or onstart where to right code to run while apps in background. i up-voted your ans :)

Comment: and my asynctask class is common for all activity, should i run this task in service or something else to solve this? like should write this task class in service onstartcommand or i shall write service class in activity and from there call this task class ?

Comment: @Imranrana07 The Service does not get interrupted during a phone call, which means that it will keep running even during a phone call, which according to what you posted, solves your problem. That's the advantage of running it in the background.

You can define the AsyncTask anywhere as long as it's visible to your Service. Then create an instance of the AsyncTask inside your service and start it there.

Comment: i am showing image and information from server, but while apps resuming after phone call or apps in background; image and information retrieved from server disappeared. will service solve this problem too? for more specific i added 2 photo to my post.

Comment: @Imranrana07 Hard to say without any code, but generally, any data kept inside the Service should not be lost as it's running in the background.

Comment: sorry to bothering you much , one more ques if you dont mind. we use singleton class extending application class most often for volley library. will this handle phone call to?

Comment: @Imranrana07 Please read more about Service. As long as it's running in the background - activity being paused or stopped shouldn't affect it, although it could in some cases, depends on how you implement it.

Answer (score 0):

```
1.

 <service
            android:name=".AsyncTaskInServiceService">
        </service>
2.

public class ServiceReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
        TelephonyManager telephony = (TelephonyManager)context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        telephony.listen(new PhoneStateListener(){
            @Override
            public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
                super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
                System.out.println("incomingNumber : " + incomingNumber);
                Toast.makeText(context,incomingNumber,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
Asynchtask().execute();//Write the code here
            }
        },PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }
```